# Nginx Redirects Subfolders

Tags: nginx

I have on my server installation of WordPress in public directory:

```
var/www/example/ - main installation of WordPress
```

In that directory I have also subdirectory WORDPRESS which has many subfolders like

```
var/www/example/WORDPRESS/1
var/www/example/WORDPRESS/2
etc.
```

Every this subfolders 1,2 have installed WordPress Blog. Everythings works ok when I use standard permalinks for wordpress for example:

```
http://www.example.net/WORDPRESS/1/?p=1
```

But when I try to change it to somethink like:

```
http://www.example.net/WORDPRESS/2015/09/27/title-of-post
```

Nginx redirect to:

```
http://www.example.net/2015/09/27/title-of-post/
```

My nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.net *.example.net;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.net/$1 permanent;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.net;
    root /var/www/example/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    location / {
        root /var/www/example/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index
}
```

How can I make subfolders work? Nginx just skips WORDPRESS subdirectory in link.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try with:

```
location /WORDPRESS/ {
    root /var/www/example/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Comment: No it doesn't work link www.example.net/WORDPRESS/wp1/some-title-of-post give only "file not found"

Comment: I updated the answer sorry I think you need to remove /WORDPRESS/ from the try_files

Comment: Also doesn't work,now it redirect to www.example.net/hello-world/ and should to www.example.net/WORDPRESS/wp1/hello-world , earlier code was closer because it redirect to www.example.net/WORDPRESS/wp1/hello-world but it shows only "file not found"